# What is the Relation in my Dataset of Hotel Reviews?

Tags: dataset, relation, relational-algebra

I have a dataset of hotel reviews. Each file in the dataset is for a different hotel. I have been asked to "Write down the relation you identify in the dataset. Ensure you include data types and the primary key." Here is an example file from my dataset:

```
<Overall Rating>4
<Avg. Price>$173
<URL>http://...

<Author>everywhereman2
<Content>Old seattle getaway...
<Date>Jan 6, 2009
<img src="http://cdn.tripadvisor.com/img2/new.gif" alt="New"/>
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>5
<Value>5
<Rooms>5
<Location>5
<Cleanliness>5
<Check in / front desk>5
<Service>5
<Business service>5

<Author>RW53
<Content>Location! Location?       view from room of nearby freeway 
<Date>Dec 26, 2008
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>3
<Value>4
<Rooms>3
<Location>2
<Cleanliness>4
<Check in / front desk>3
<Service>-1
<Business service>-1

...new review e.t.c
```

The Author to Business service section(line 5 to line 18) represents a review for the hotel. The file will then continue for however many reviews there are for that hotel repeating lines 5 through 18. I hope that makes sense. Here is what I think the relation is:

```
HotelReview(String: Author, String: Content, Date: Date, String: img src, Int: No. Reader, Int: No. Helpful, Int: Overall, Int: Value, Int: Rooms, Int: Location, Int: Cleanliness, Int: Checkin / front desk, Int: Service, Int: Business Service)
```

or would it be

```
HotelReview(Int: Overall Rating, Int: Avg. Price, String: URL)
```

I may be way off as I am new to this stuff, I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: can anyone help? I can answer any questions you have

Comment: would the primary key be the URL?

Comment: or the content maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm not the best to provide an answer, but I'll give it a try.

First, you might want to lookup some books or blogs on database schema design. This should give you general guidance on how to approach this task.

Then, from the data shown you might recognize 2 entities:

- Hotel (from the header section)
  With the following attributes:

  - OverallRating int
  - AveragePrice  int
  - URL  url or text

  The first two could actually be values derived (calculated) from some other source, but as presented this would resemble true attribute values)
  Probably from this, *URL* is the primary key, if there is no other better suited value that is not shown with the example.
- HotelReview (from the repeated sections)
  With attributes:

  - Hotel  (an url foreign key from the Hotel entity)
  - Autor text (or maybe a foreign key to an author table if authors are "well known")
  - Date date
  - img url or text (or is this referring to a further table?)
  - all the value attributes using type Int

  With the given data there is no "good" primary key for this relation. All you have is *Author* and *Date* as a combined key. But using it would imply an author may just provide a review once a day. If this is a reasonable restriction, the go ahead. Otherwise, you need to introduce more attributes (e.g. *time of review* to get by this restriction or simply introduce a sequence number for the reviews that uniquely identifies reviews and may serve as a primary key.

With the indicated types you should of course follow the types available with your type system. If there is none, then indicate most precise type and provide a list of types and semantic. E.g. you could use a type *score* indicating this being an integer value from -1 to 10 where -1 indicates "deliberately no value" and the others are the potential scores with *10* being best score. and then use thos for the different categories.

Comment: Wow thanks this is really helpful, splitting it into two entities makes everything seem more clearer. Can't award my 50rep bounty for 20 hours but will do when the time comes